# ExtJS6: Passing entire object or 2 fields in gridpanel's columns

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

While building GridPanel's column values I need to lookup for a field if that field does not have a value, it should look for another field and render it as a column value. Now as per [ExtJS6 docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1-classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-dataIndex), we could pass a single data attribute to `dataIndex` and mould value via rendered function. But there is no mention how one can use fallback attribute if mentioned field does not have a value.

Here is snippet:

```
{
  text: 'Title',
  flex: 1,
  dataIndex: '<how-to-pass-object-itself-or-two-fields>',
  renderer: function(value, metaData) {
    return '<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>' +  value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The renderer function has more in-parameters.

You can grab all fields off of the record.

```
var DEFAULT_VALUE = '';

{
    dataIndex : 'a' // or could be 'b', or 'c' or etc…
    renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
        var fieldA = record.get('a');
        var fieldB = record.get('b');
        var fieldC = record.get('c');

        // …

        return value || DEFAULT_VALUE; // ?
    }
}
```

In the return statement, just replace `DEFAULT_VALUE` with one of your other field values or an actual default value.

Answer (score 1):

If your grid is sortable on the client side, you should be careful when using `renderer` for rendering different record values in your column.

You can also look at [convert](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.data.field.Field.html#method-convert) method in `Ext.data.field.Field`